# EL within EL in oozie workflow

Tags: el, oozie, oozie-workflow

Getting EL_ERROR with below oozie workflow code snippet at line # 3 and 4. Please advise.

```
1. <decision name="chooseFruit">
2. <switch>
3. <case to="apple">${fs:dirSize(${path_hdfs_inprocess}/${wf:id()}) gt 0}</case>
4. <case to="carrot">${fs:dirSize(${path_hdfs_inprocess}/${wf:id()}) gt 0}</case>
5. <default to="On_Failure"/>
6. </switch>
7. </decision>
```

Comment: Don't nest `${` / expressions

Comment: Thanks @JasperdeVries